# Deleted Horizon still get errors of redis

Tags: laravel, redis, horizon

I'v deleted Laravel Horizon package totally from my project and remove Redis too totally and using Memcached instead.

But at the 00:00 time of every days some Logs appears for Horizon trying to connect Redis, but since Redis is not available in my server, So it cant connect and get errors.

I do anything u think, but issue is still there.

I deleted Predis package too but still erorrs.

```
Connection refused [unix:/var/run/redis/redis.sock] {"exception":"[object] (Predis\\Connection\\ConnectionException(code: 111): Connection refused
```

Comment: Have you tried “composer dumpautoload”? Not sure if this will help but when I deleted packages from my project, I kept getting errors asking where they were and I found that running composer dumpautoload helped... probably won’t help you but worth a try

Comment: I did composer dump-autoload, No changes